# Crash on Android phone with expo, react Native and firebase

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, crash, expo

I'm doing an app in react Native, Expo and Firebase.

I've got some crash when i test it on an Android phone.

I recently use Test Lab from firebase to test my app and I've got this error:

> Your app uses 4 non-SDK interfaces, which are incompatible with Android P+.

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "android": {
    "versionCode": 2
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "github:react-native-async-storage/async-storage",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^7.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^2.4.3",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.0.0",
    "expo": "^41.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~9.1.2",
    "expo-constants": "~10.1.3",
    "expo-device": "~3.2.0",
    "expo-firebase-analytics": "~4.0.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-localization": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.11.6",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "hermes-engine": "^0.8.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "3.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.15.0",
    "npm": "^7.14.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-instantsearch-native": "^6.10.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "0.0.19",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-read-more-text": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "8.3.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

If someone know if I use an package that not compatible ore something like that
(The app in prod crash too)